# Mail: There was an error testing your email settings

Tags: emails

I'm trying to use mailgun to send emails. I'm on my local machine and I get the error: "There was an error testing your email settings." The API key matches up correctly and nothing of significance seems to be showing up in my logs. Can someone suggest another way of debugging this? The error message isn't too helpful on it's own. Thanks.

Comment: Is ``devMode`` enabled?

Comment: I have the same error. And when I look in the logs there is simply the same error again without further explanation: `web.log` $_SESSION = [ 'bd62416aa8538ede709019a5e113eea5__flash' => [ 'cp-error' => 1 ] 'bd62416aa8538ede709019a5e113eea5__auth_access' => [ 0 => 'editStructure:6' 1 => 'saveAssetInVolume:110' ] '1031b8c41dfff97a311a7ac99863bdc5__token' => '••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••' '1031b8c41dfff97a311a7ac99863bdc5__id' => 1 '1031b8c41dfff97a311a7ac99863bdc5__expire' => 1603106907 'commerce_customer' => '1' 'commerce_c

Comment: Check the logs near where you grabbed that from for `[error]` or `[warning]`

Comment: Aha. Searching for `Warning` instead of error did the trick. 2020-10-20 13:15:30 [-][1][-][warning][application] Error sending email: Connection to tcp://mail.domain.com:992 Timed Out

Answer (score 2):

Check your Craft `storage/logs` folder for the underlying error message.  You can also use these knowledge base articles to help debug what's going on based on what you find:

https://craftcms.com/knowledge-base/troubleshooting-email-errors

https://craftcms.com/knowledge-base/why-doesnt-craft-send-emails